# Submit an extended version of a computer science conference paper to a non-CS journal

Tags: journals, conference, computer-science, extended-paper

I know that CS journals usually accept extended version of a conference paper with some, say 10%, new contents. But is it still true for non-CS journals?

Comment: Why on earth would you submit a CS paper to a non-CS journal?

Comment: It might a paper whose topic is bordering on, say, discrete mathematics. I have colleagues in the maths department that publish in both mathematics and computer science outlets.

Comment: @HansHüttel That is certainly a possibility, but I find it curious submitting a paper to a CS conference and then submitting an extended version to a non-CS journal.

Comment: Is there any legal restrictions that you signed as part of your submission and acceptance to the conference?

Comment: @FrankFYC No....

Comment: Then you ask the journal you'd like to submit your paper. They would be best to give you a thumbs up or down.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be a better strategy to submit the extended version to a CS journal and a different approach of the problem with a different point of view (not just 10% extension) to the non-CS journal.

For the reader of the non-CS journal having a non-CS way of expressing the problem/solution would be more beneficial. For the reader that sees both submissions there will not be a feeling of simply trying to get more publications with the same paper (not meaning to be rude or anything!).

Answer (score 0):

Most journals expect at least 30% difference from any previous published version of your work. **Some** CS journals do not require such a change, or do not enforce it. In other journals this requirement may be strictly enforced or less strictly — this depends on the editor and the specific journal.